# Tim Dashboard React doesn't work with Fixed position

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using Tim dark dashboard for react at https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard and I am having problems using fixed position. I have created a login page outside of the main `AdminLayout`:

```
<Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route
            path="/admin"
            render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />}
        />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

The login page is as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  Row,
  Col,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormText,
  Input,
  Label,
  Button
} from "reactstrap";

const Login = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    const { setAlert } = useContext(AlertContext);
    const history = useHistory();


const tapHandler = () => {
    setAlert({ message: 'hello', variant: 'success'})
};

return(
    <div className="d-flex vh-100">
        <Row className="m-auto align-self-center">
            <Col>
                <Card className="login-card">
                    <CardHeader>
                        <CardTitle>
                            <h4>Login</h4>
                        </CardTitle>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <FormGroup controlId="email">
                                <Label for="email">E-mail</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    id="email"
                                    placeholder="name@example.com"
                                    innerRef={register({ required: true })}
                                />
                                <FormText>
                                    <span className="text-danger">
                                        {errors.email && 'E-mail required'}
                                    </span>
                                </FormText>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup controlId="password">
                                <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="password"
                                    name="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    placeholder="password"
                                    innerRef={register({ required: true })}
                                />
                                <FormText>
                                    <span className="text-danger">
                                        {errors.password &&
                                            'Password required'
                                        }
                                    </span>
                                </FormText>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <Button color="primary" block type="submit">
                                Login
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                        <Button onClick={tapHandler}>Tap</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
         
        // Fixed doesn't work here
        <div className="some-div" />
    </div>
  );
}; 

export default Login;
```

The div at the bottom of the page that uses `some-div` doesn't work with fixed positioning, css as follows:

```
.some-div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

It just sits at the bottom left of the page. It's not respecting the fixed coordinate system. Has anyone else run into this type of issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output when I break down your JSX in a minimal example:

```
<div className="d-flex vh-100">
  <Row className="m-auto align-self-center">
  </Row>

  <div className="some-div">some div</div>
</div>
```

You have a flex container as a parent of both your Login container and the `.some-div` container. Where Login and `.some-div` are siblings. So if anything (even *without* applying the fixed positioning you mentioned), the output display should be that the Login container is on the left side and the `.some-div` container is on the right side - the work of flexbox.

So at that point, I can't see why your `.some-div`

> just sits at the bottom left of the page

`fixed` positioning should properly kick in when you include your custom stylesheet.

```
import "./styles.css";
```

You can find a working example by clicking my CodeSandBox button below. You can use it as a basis of comparison.

[image: Edit React Bootstrap Tim Dashboard]